# soap class run correctly on localhost but don't run on server

Tags: php, soap

i have a problem with soap class in php. i have write a code to send sms via a sms panel. these codes run correctly on localhost (when run codes by xampp on my pc) but this code don't work when i run them on server. the php versions are same on both of them (localhost and xampp)

```
<?php
$FORM="30005966371";    
$USERNAME="xxxx";
$PASSWORD="12345";  
$DOMAIN="0098";
//---- variables ----
$TO="0935xxxxxxx";
$TEXT="test msg";
//-------------------
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$sms_client = new SoapClient('http://webservice.0098sms.com/service.asmx?wsdl',array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));
$parameters['username'] = $USERNAME;
$parameters['password'] = $PASSWORD;
$parameters['mobileno'] = $TO;
$parameters['pnlno'] = $FORM;
$parameters['text']=$TEXT;
$parameters['isflash'] =false;
echo $sms_client->SendSMS($parameters)->SendSMSResult;
?>
```

when i run above codes on localhost the message sends correctly but when run this code on server the following error returns:

> bimehco.ir is currently unable to handle this request.
> HTTP ERROR 500

i enabled soap extension in php.ini file on server but it still dont work correctly.

Comment: Look at the error logs on the server. You can't get server errors client side (or shouldn't)

Comment: Maybe it has to do with a missing extension on your server. Checking the error log as suggested should give you more clues.

Comment: tnx. but error log is empty

Comment: It 's because your request is wrong and the server does not receive the expected xml message. Enhance the options when initializing the `SoapClient` class. Enable exceptions and tracing. With these options the `SoapClient` class throws exceptions that you can catch. Further more you can output the created xml string by using the `__getLastRequest` and `__getLastResponse` methods of the soap client.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

my soap codes were true and don't have any problem. it was a problem on host.
you can use above codes for soap.
or you can use curve function instead.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of the `SoapClient` class should look as follows when searching for errors.

```
$wsdl = 'http://webservice.0098sms.com/service.asmx?wsdl';
$options = [
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'trace' => true,
];

try {
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
    // do your request stuff here
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    echo $fault->getMessage();

    if ($client instanceof SoapClient) {
        echo $client->__getLastRequest();
        echo $client->__getLastResponse();
    }
}
```